# string.toUpperCase() and string.toLowercase() not printing

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, uppercase, lowercase

(preface) I actually believe this to be a simple question but im fairly
new to programming so it is a bit frustrating for me. This questions pertains
to a problem with how uppercase and lowercase string may override each other when displaying executed code.

Code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //need for the scanner class

public class Manip
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String city; //to hold the user input   

        //create the scanner object here
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get the favorite city
        //prompt the user to input the favorite city
        System.out.print("Enter favorite city: ");      

        //read and store into city
        city = keyboard.nextLine();

        //display the number of characters.
        System.out.print("String Length :" );
        System.out.println(city.length());

        //display the city in all upper case
        System.out.println(city.toUpperCase() );

        //Display the city in all lower case
        System.out.println(city.toLowerCase() );

        //Display the first character

        keyboard.next();
    }
}
```

the output of the code is-

```
enter favorite city: dallas
String Length :6
dallas
```

the desired output is-

```
enter favorite city: dallas
String Length :6
DALLAS
dallas
```

I'm wondering why it is not printing "dallas" twice, as uppercase AND lowercase letters. it seems to be overwriting the input

Comment: Please post all pertinent code here as code-formatted text, and not as an image. None of us can copy your image into our IDE's and then compile and run it or modify it. An image of code does us little good. Best in fact if you could post a valid [sscce](http://sscce.org), a very small program that compiles and runs for us and that shows us your problem.

Comment: And same for the display. Most important, please go through the [help] sections on How-to-Ask, and take a look at [I'm new to SO, what are some things I should do, and what things will I likely want to do, that I shouldn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/522444)

Comment: You aren't running the code you think you are (you probably need to recompile). And, **never** post code as images. `System.out.printf("%s (length = %d) %s %s%n", city, city.length(), city.toLowerCase(), city.toUpperCase());`

Comment: works fine for me buddy.

Comment: @Ben I don't see any error here, but I do have a question. Why is the following line at the end of your code `keyboard.next();`? is there any reason for this line?

Comment: ok so the problem is that I need the code to output dallas in lowcase, and in uppercase letters. so  

DALLAS
dallas

but its only outputting in lowercase letters. I think the "toUppercase" and "toLowercase" commands are overwriting each other. 

("is there any reason for that line") oh I suppose I left that part of the code on towards the end. it doesnt do anything its part of a longer code for an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code just as it is, and it printed it both in uppercase and lowercase, but I noticed you had a comment that said `//Display the first character`, and following it, `keyboard.next()`. This was the only incorrect part. To print the first letter of a string(in this case the string is `city`), use this line: `System.out.println(city.substring(0,1).toUpperCase());` below is an example of the output:

```
Enter favorite city: dallas.          
String Length :6
DALLAS
dallas
D
```

Comment: there's not much to answer here, but I thought i would say something...

Comment: @ben be sure to close your `Scanner` method, using `keyboard.close()` after there is no more input needed. This is not necessary, but advised for neatness

Comment: Hm this made it work. I didnt notice I had that towards the end, perhaps it was overwriting the output. Thank you for addressing that question as well  . it was what I needed to figure out next =/, thank you for your help.

Comment: @ben You can accept an answer if it helped you.